# displaying user info from website inside Android application

Tags: android

Hey I'm building an app that will allow a user to log into a site (mygranturismo.net) and then will display their personal info, (cars owned, trophies earned, level status, etc) in a layout on the screen. i need to be able to get this info and place certain bits right where i want, also some may be clickable links to other info inside the site. I don't want to simply link to the site, i want to access certain parts and display then in my custom app. an example would be the difference between twitter on Android vs twitter on a pc browser. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is your question here? To implement this would require a whole host of components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you're describing is a native mobile application to work with an existing website that's not optimized for mobile. If you own the website, you can create private pages for simplified data retrieval. If it's a website that you don't own, you will need to read the raw HTML and extract the useful info from it. How you do it is up to you, but it will involve string searches and cut/paste of info from the HTML text. The danger in doing this is that if the website owner changes the layout of his pages it will probably break your application.

Comment: I agree  if you are the owner of the website create a soap or a rest web-service  soap can be easily accessed using the ksoap2 library http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/   there is also a client side proxy generator

Comment: or create a web-interface for a mobile device you can show it using a web view like a native app makes updates easier :)